# Looping over Range of Cells?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I would like to create a script, I got two (2) workbooks and they are kind of related, on the first one I would like to activate a sheet find and offset one cell and select all the info. and in case the cell contains a "yes" in the new one would paste "Yes" instead of all the info. in the previous workbook.

```
Sub test2()
Dim SingleCell As Range
Dim Listcells As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks("OLD CAD").Sheets("Contract History-Modifications").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Find(" CM Name/Number", MatchCase:=True).Select
Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(2, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell.Address, Range(ActiveCell.Address).End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(0, 13).Select
'ActiveSheet.Range(Selection.Address)
'MsgBox (Selection.Address)

Set Listcells = Range(Selection.Address)
      For Each SingleCell In Listcells
'Select Case True
'            Case Is = InStr(1, (SingleCell.Value), "Yes") > 0
   If InStr(1, (SingleCell.Value), "Yes") > 0 Then
   Workbooks("NEW CAD").Sheets("Contract History-Modifications").Activate
                        ActiveSheet.Range("i:j").Find("A. Did the CM change the price of the transaction?", MatchCase:=True).Activate
                            Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(1, 0).Select
                            Range(ActiveCell.Address).Value = "Yes"
                                     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
'End Select
Next SingleCell
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question/issue?

Comment: what do you mean in `ActiveSheet.Range("i:j").Find("A. Did the CM change the price of the transaction?", MatchCase:=True).Activate` ? Activate a cell where there is a sentence _"A. Did the CM change the price of the transaction?"_ ?

Comment: I have two files (Old CAD & New CAD) I'm trying to update those files, copy the data from the Old one to the New one, but the format of each one is different, and I'm trying to use "Find" to match the things I want to copy. 

My main problem right now is that I want to create like a loop because my Old CAD data used to have specific details and in my New CAD just need Yes/No. 

So the loop I'm trying is to store a variable range, and in each cell in the range want to know if contains Yes, so if it's true my value on my New CAD would be yes, and if it contains something else no.

Comment: I try the current scrip but I think the main problem is that it doesn't keep me the range.